# Получение форматированной коллекции в Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.8

Получаю такой результат:

```
1: {71: [,…]}
  71: [,…]
    0: {chat_id: 71, name: "Клиент", photo: null, type_id: 1}
2: {72: [{chat_id: 72, name: "Эксперт",…}]}
  72: [{chat_id: 72, name: "Эксперт",…}]
    0: {chat_id: 72, name: "Эксперт",…}
```

Нужен такой формат:

```
1: {71: {,…}}
  71: {chat_id: 71, name: "Клиент", photo: null, type_id: 1}
2: {72: {chat_id: 72, name: "Эксперт",…}}
  72: {chat_id: 72, name: "Эксперт",…}
```

мой код:

```
Chat::query()
  ->select('chats.id as chat_id', 'name', 'photo', 'type_id')
  ->where('task_id', $task_id)
  ->whereIn('type_id', [1, 2, 3])
  ->leftJoin('users', function ($join) use ($user_id) {
    $join->on(function ($query) use ($user_id, $join) {
      $query
        ->on('chats.user_id2', '=', 'users.id')
          ->where('chats.user_id2', '!=', $user_id)
          ->where('chats.type_id', 1)
       ->orOn('chats.user_id1', '=', 'users.id')
         ->where('chats.user_id1', '!=', $user_id);
    });
  })
  ->get()
  ->groupBy(['type_id', 'chat_id']);
```

Comment: `->map(fn ($item) => (object)value($item));` предположительно, что-то такое добавить надо, после `->groupBy(['type_id', 'chat_id'])`. P.S. чаты не корректно спроектированы